# $N(X)$ denotes collection of all nets of $X$. $T:N(X)\to \mathcal{P}(X)$ be a map such that $T\{x_\delta\}=T\{y_\gamma\}$ if one is subnet of other.

Tags: general-topology, nets

> Let $X$ be a non-empty set. $N(X)$ denotes the collection of all nets on $X$ and $\mathcal{P}(X)$ denotes the collection of all subsets of $X$. Let $T:N(X)\to \mathcal{P}(X)$ be a map satisfying the condition $T\{x_\lambda\}_{\Lambda}=T\{y_\gamma\}_{\Gamma}$ if one of $\{x_\lambda\}_{\Lambda}$ and $\{y_\gamma\}_{\Gamma}$ is a subnet of the other.
> Define $\tau=\{A\subset X|\ T\{x_\lambda\}_{\Lambda}\subset A^c\text{ for every net }\{x_\lambda\}_{\Lambda}\subset A^c\}$

We have to prove that $\tau$ is a topology on $X$. I have tried the problem in the following manner-

1. $\emptyset\in \tau$ since given any net $\{x_\lambda\}_{\Lambda}\subset (\emptyset)^c=X$, we always have $T\{x_\lambda\}_{\Lambda}\subset (\emptyset)^c=X$ . Again, $X\in \tau$ since $X^c=\emptyset$
2. Let $\{A_i|\ i\in I\}\subset \tau$. Then let $\{x_\lambda\}_{\Lambda}\subset \left(\bigcup A_i\right)^c=\bigcap A_i^c\implies \{x_\lambda\}_{\Lambda}\subset A_i^c\ \forall i\implies T\{x_\lambda\}_{\Lambda}\subset A_i^c\ \forall i\implies T\{x_\lambda\}_{\Lambda}\subset \bigcap A_i^c=\left(\bigcup A_i\right)^c$. Hence, $\bigcup A_i\in \tau$.
3. Let $A,B\in \tau$ and $\{x_\lambda\}_{\Lambda}\in (A\cap B)^c=A^c\cup B^c$. Now we have to prove $T\{x_\lambda\}_{\Lambda}\subset A^c\cup B^c$.
   Now I define $\Gamma=\{\lambda\in\Lambda|\ x_\lambda\in A^c\}, \Sigma=\{\lambda\in\Lambda|\ x_\lambda\in B^c\}$. Now if I can prove at least one of $\Lambda_1,\Lambda_2$ is directed set then I will construct a subnet of $\{x_\lambda\}_{\Lambda}$, and use the property of $T$ to achieve our goal. But I'm to prove that at least one of $\Gamma,\Sigma$ is directed set, although I have shown that both $\Gamma, \Sigma$ satisfies reflexivity and transitivity condition. But we have to show the third condition which is $$\text{If }\lambda_1,\lambda_2\in \Gamma\text{ (or }\Sigma\text{)}, \exists \lambda_3\in \Gamma\text{ (or }\Sigma\text{) such that } \lambda_3\ge\lambda_1,\lambda_2$$

Can anyone help me with this regard? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What notion of subnet are you using? Do you have an example of a valid map $T$? What motivates its definition ? You do know $N(X)$ is not a set, right? Or is the index set fixed?

Comment: $\overline{x}=\{x_\lambda\}_{\Lambda}, \overline{y}=\{y_\gamma\}_{\Gamma}$ be two nets from directed set $\Lambda$ and $\Gamma$ respectively. $\overline{y}$ is said to be subnet of $\overline{x}$ if there is a map $h:\Gamma\to\Lambda$ such that (a) if $\gamma_1\ge\gamma_2$, then $h(\gamma_1)\ge h(\gamma_2)$, (b) $h$ is cofinal i.e. $\forall \lambda\in\Lambda,\exists \gamma\in \Gamma$ such that $h(\gamma)\ge \lambda$ and (c) $y_{\gamma}=x_{h(\gamma)}\ \forall \gamma\in\Gamma$.

Comment: OK the Willard definition with order preserving maps. And an example of a map $T$?

Comment: I don't have any such specific example but we have to prove $\tau$ is a topology.

Comment: So there might not even be an example? Why waste time on it then?

Comment: Maybe it’s the condition $T((x_\delta))= T((y_\gamma))$ if one is a subnet of the other, not “iff”. Then I can think of examples.

Comment: Yes, it will be "if" I think so.

Comment: Then $T(x)$ can be the set of limits of the net, say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Gamma \cup \Sigma = \Lambda$ so one of them is cofinal in $\Lambda$ ( if neither, then the directedness gives an immediate contradiction ), so say that $\Gamma$ is cofinal. But then $\Gamma$ defines a subnet of $x$ living on $A^c$ (the cofinality ensures its also directed as a suborder) and so has the same $T$ set as $x$, and as $A\in \tau$ that $T(x) \subseteq A^c$ and we’re done.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I forget the result - Cofinal subset of a directed set is directed. From this, the claim follows.

Comment: @DeltaEpsilon note that we only need the if not the iff in this argument.